# Undefined method for relation issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have a standard has_many/belongs_to association in a rails 4 app.

Here's my rake code:

```
task remove_faked: :environment do
   destroyed = Movie.where(fake: true).posters.where("created_at < ?",  1.minute.ago).destroy_all
   puts "Done. #{destroyed.length} records deleted."
end
```

but I get the error: `undefined method posters for #<Movie::ActiveRecord_Relation`

I checked `Poster.last` in my console and it has an associated movie_id with a corresponding movie id. I can also do associations within my app like Poster.all.where(movie_id: @movie.id) fine.

Comment: You want to delete movies or posters ? I got confused about that.. :)

Comment: I want to delete posters

Answer (score 2):

movie.rb

```
has_many :posters, dependent: destroy
```

poster.rb

```
belongs_to :movie
```

task file

```
task remove_faked: :environment do
   destroyed = Movie.include(:posters).where(fake: true).where("created_at < ?",  1.minute.ago).destroy_all
   puts "Done. #{destroyed.length} records deleted."
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
destroyed = Movie.where(fake: true).posters.where("created_at < ?",  1.minute.ago).destroy_all
```

with

```
destroyed = Movie.includes(:posters).where("fake = ? && posters.created_at < ?", true, 1.minute.ago).references(:posters).destroy_all
```

This only destroys fake movies that satisfy the given conditions. If you have used the dependent: :destroy option for movies, in that case the posters belonging to a movie that is being destroyed will be destroyed along with the movie.

Answer (score 0):

Since your comments seem to suggest that you only want to destroy the `Poster`s and not the `Movie`s try this:

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posters      
end

class Poster < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :movie

  scope :for_fake_movie, ->{ joins(:movie).where(movie:{fake: true}) }
  scope :since,->(time_frame){where("created_at < ?", time_frame)}
end
```

Then the task would look like this

```
task remove_faked: :environment do
   destroyed = Poster.for_fake_movie.since(1.minute.ago).destroy_all
   puts "Done. #{destroyed.length} records deleted."
end
```

Scoping makes code much clearer and helps move the business logic into the model rather than cluttering controllers, views and in this case rake tasks. If you wanted to delete the movies too I would go with

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posters, dependent: :destroy 

  scope :fake, ->{where(fake: true) }
  scope :posters_since, ->(time_frame){joins(:posters).where("posters.created_at < ?", time_frame)}
end

class Poster < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :movie
end
```

Then the task would be

```
task remove_faked: :environment do
   destroyed = Movie.fake.posters_since(1.minute.ago).destroy_all
   puts "Done. #{destroyed.length} records deleted."
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`where` results in a set of objects. Your `posters` association is defined on an object itself, so it cannot be applied this way.

I would rather delve into some details about how RDBMSs work.

First of all, I follow a simple rule: query the class instances of which you want to receive. You want `Poster`s here, but you are querying `Movie`s. I'm going to do the other way round and query `Poster`s instead.

You have a powerful concept of **join** in your database, that, obviously, joins rows from two tables together on a specific condition. You could think of it as it takes each pair of rows, checks the condition, and if it's true, puts the combination into the internal buffer. We will still be selecting only posters' fields, but now we can use movies' fields too:

```
Poster.joins(:movie) # singular, as in association, belongs_to in this case
```

This changes... nothing so far. But now it allows you to impose some conditions on posters, based on associated movies.

`merge` does that, it applies a scope, possibly even from a different model. Without a join that would have given invalid SQL. Not this time!

```
Poster.joins(:movie).merge(Movie.where(fake: true))
```

What we get here is posters that belong to a movie that has `fake: true`. Wow, eh? Not just slap your own condition on top of it and do your thing:

```
Poster.joins(:movie)
      .merge(Movie.where(fake: true))
      .where("created_at < ?",  1.minute.ago)
      .destroy_all
```